# Oracle 11G DB : Result from 'clob' type column in view changed while using the view in a where clause

Tags: sql, oracle, view, oracle11g

I have the current query that i'm running in Oracle:

```
    WITH viewa
     AS (SELECT c.columna
         FROM   sometable c
         LEFT JOIN othertable u
         ON ( c.id = u.id )
         WHERE id= '111' 
         ORDER BY c.created_date)
SELECT columna
FROM   (SELECT rownum AS row_num,
               t.*
        FROM   viewa t)
WHERE  row_num > (SELECT CASE
                           WHEN ( Count(*) > 100 ) THEN Count(*) - 100
                           ELSE 0
                         END AS num
                  FROM   viewa)
```

the idea is to always get the first 100 rows.
as you can see, i'm creating a view at the beginning and use it twice:
in the from and in the where.

i'm doing that so i wouldn't need to fetch the first select twice and it also make the query more readable.

notice that  **columna is of type CLOB!!**
when i'm doing the same query with other column types its working!
so its probably something related to the clob column

The weird think is that the results that im getting are empty values even though i have values in the DB!

when i'm removing the subselect in the where i'm getting the right result:

```
WITH viewa
     AS (SELECT c.columna
         FROM   sometable c
         LEFT JOIN othertable u
         ON ( c.id = u.id )
         WHERE id = '111' 
         ORDER BY c.created_date)
SELECT columna
FROM   (SELECT rownum AS row_num,
               t.*
        FROM   viewa t)
WHERE  row_num > 0
```

seems like Oracle is turning the values for the Clob column "columnA" into null when using the view in the where.

is someone familiar with that?
know how to go around it ?

i solved it with a different query but i still would like to know if Oracle does change the view while fetching from it?

thank you

Comment: You say "the first 100" rows, but there is no ```ORDER BY``` clause in your query anywhere. Oracle does not guarantee any order.

Answer (score 0):

Without sample data this is hard but I'm guessing the reason is you're depending on rownum. Use the `FETCH` clause instead to limit the number of rows.

```
WITH viewa
  AS (SELECT c.columna
        FROM sometable c
             LEFT JOIN othertable u ON ( c.id = u.id )
      -- an order by clause should go here 
         FETCH FIRST 100 ROWS ONLY)
SELECT columna
FROM   viewa
```

But you don't need that CTE at all, just do

```
SELECT c.columna
        FROM sometable c
             LEFT JOIN othertable u ON ( c.id = u.id )
      -- an order by clause should go here 
         FETCH FIRST 100 ROWS ONLY
```

Note that the "first" rows are not guaranteed to be a specific set of rows unless you explicitly add an `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: ill try your solution thank you.

but its not related to the row num
it happens only to column from type clob, all the rest got the same data in both of the queries

Comment: Got the same data in both of the queries - that doesn't mean anything. The optimizer could use another execution path when you change the where clause. Without order by this is a very unreliable query. It also makes sense to create a reproducible case. That will make it possible for the community to give you a proper answer.

Comment: ok i've got Oracke 11g, so it doesn't have the 'fetch' unfortunately

i'm using order by, wanted to make it simpler for the community

Comment: pls update your question with the correct tags - I'll remove my answer since it's irrelevant for 11g

Answer (score 0):

Since 11g does not have FETCH FIRST, you can just use `rownumber` as the limiting criteria. See Example at [Oracle Live](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/f?p=590:6:6208136787696:::::&success_msg=QWN0aW9uIFByb2Nlc3NlZA%7E%7E%2FKbUuZViubkFIn2os0kU7f7sP3GlQW-SkBo-t4iBzPcpe5LhzRjEn9DhZZA2HBIr1XubKiasGkuU6elU4uguI-Q)

```
select columna, created_date 
  from (  
         select c.columna, c.created_date   
           from sometable  c 
           left join othertable u 
                  on ( c.id = u.id ) 
          where c.id = '111'  
          order by c.created_date 
      )  
where rownum <= 10;
```